# count even elements in a Doubly Linked list using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I have two functions one NumsEven() and the other NumsEvenHelper(Node* ptr) I have a list with {2,4,5,10} I am supposed to count the even numbers using recursion this is what I have up to now:

```
template <typename Data_t>
Data_t DLinkedList<Data_t>::NumEven() {
    Node* ptr = _head;
    return NumEvenHelper(ptr);
}
template <typename Data_t>
Data_t DLinkedList<Data_t>::NumEvenHelper(Node* ptr) {
    
    ptr = _head;
    
    if (empty()) return 0;
    
    else if ((ptr->_data % 2 == 0))
        return 1 + NumEvenHelper(ptr->_next);
    
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you show? Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: As a hint about your problem (something which a little ***debugging*** should have helped you find): What happens if a node have an *odd* value?

Comment: On an unrelated note, I assume that `Data_t` is the type of the contained data? Why do your function return it? What happens if `Data_t` is not an integer type? Wouldn't it make more sense for the functions to return an `unsigned int`?

Comment: "I am supposed to count the even numbers using recursion" So doing it without recursion is not a problem? Do you have code for that?

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this problem, you can add two member functions: first one would be public and the other one would be private:

```cpp
public:
    std::size_t countEven() const noexcept;

private:
    std::size_t countEven(Node *node) const noexcept;
```

While the first member function will be used by the user of doubly linked list, second member function will be used in the actual recursion / calculation.

```cpp
std::size_t countEven() const noexcept {
    return countEven(_head);
}

std::size_t countEven(Node *node) const noexcept {
    if (nullptr != node) {
        if (curr->_data % 2 == 0) {
            return countEven(node->next) + 1;  // since _data is even, increment by one
        } else {
            return countEven(node->next);  // since _data is not even, don't increment
        }
    } else {
        return 0; // in case we reach the end of list, we need to return starting value for counting
    }
}
```

Implication is, of course, that the `_data` member is integer.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have *two* problems... Both of these are easily discoverable by simple debugging.

The first problem is that you have no case to handle *odd* data values in the list.

If `ptr->_data` is odd, then the `NumEvenHelper` function will just end without you returning anything. This will lead to *undefined behavior* as your program assumes that the function will return a valid value.

The function will also stop the recursion on odd values, so even if you have even values later in the list those won't be counted.

The simple solution is to simply add an `else` case where you just do the recursive call but without adding `1`:

```
if (empty())
    return 0;
else if ((ptr->_data % 2 == 0))
    return 1 + NumEvenHelper(ptr->_next);
else  // Is odd
    return NumEvenHelper(ptr->_next);
```

---

The second problem is that your helper function *always* set `ptr` to point to `_head`, and disregard the argument passed.

This will lead to infinite recursion on non-empty lists, as then the recursive call effectively will be:

```
NumEvenHelper(_head->_next);
```

You should *not* have that assignment inside the helper function.

---

Now for a little "trick" (that will make your code harder to read and understand) that makes it so you don't have to have the `if` and not bother with the `else`: A boolean result (like the result from a comparison) can be implicitly converted to an `int` value, with `1` for `true` and `0` for `false`.

That means you can use boolean conditions as part or arithmetic calculations in place of `1` or `0`.

Like for example:

```
if (empty())
    return 0;

// No else here

return (ptr->_data % 2 == 0) + NumEvenHelper(ptr->_next);
```

If the value is even that will add `1` to the result of the recursive call, otherwise it will add `0`.